# Is function substitution valid in proofs? If so, what are the restrictions?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, fake-proofs

For example, let us say I have used an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof to show that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$.

Then to prove all of the other properties of a limit, can't I just continuously substitute?

For limit of a constant, $f(x)=c$; for sum and different properties $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ and $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$, respectively; for product and quotient properties $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ and $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, respectively; finally, for constant multiple $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, where $g(x)=c$ and $c$ is some arbitrary constant.

This feels cheaty. I missing something? For example, since I am assuming I have already shown $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ via an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, does these mean all of these proofs are just $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs by proxy? As in, to show $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ for $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$, in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, will I just have to effectively prove $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)+h(x) = L$, thereby making the $f(x)$ obselete?

Comment: If I am interpreting your question correctly, the answer is no, you are not allowed to *just substitute*.  For example, it is true that $$ \left[ ~\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L_1, ~\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = L_2 ~\right] \implies \lim_{x\to a} \left[ ~f(x) + g(x) ~\right] = L_1 + L_2.$$  However, although this result is true, it **must be proven**.  Typically, a Real Analysis (AKA Calculus) textbook will offer an $~\epsilon, ~\delta~$ proof of this assertion.

Comment: Hi! I am aware of the ϵ-δ proof of this assertion. However, if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ and $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) + h(x) = L$, no? If so, then substitution is a valid way to arrive at a proof. So my question is to prove the first portion (lim of f(x)), am I secretly just proving the second portion (lim of g(x)+f(x))?

Comment: If you have proved $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ and you have defined $g$ and $h$ such that $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$, then yes, you know that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (g(x)+h(x)) = L$. That's what $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ means. (But note my use of parentheses--they help clarify what it is you mean.) There's nothing remarkable about this; it just says that there is more than one way to write $f(x).$ It doesn't say anything about $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ individually. It certainly has nothing to do with what people usually mean by a "sum property".

Comment: @DavidK I understand. That is verification of my doubt. By defining $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ I have *only* proven the limits $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (g(x)+h(x)) = L$. But this cannot be extrapolated to any two arbitrary functions. Thank you!

Comment: [Equality and its axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) on Wikipedia

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can equality be defined in first-order logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125616/how-can-equality-be-defined-in-first-order-logic)